# nodejs. What library should I use for session storing in MongoDB

Tags: session, mongodb, node.js

I've found three library of session storing in MongoDB: **connect-mongodb**, **connect-mongo**, **connect-session-mongo**

Which is the best?

**EDIT:** So if I'll use connect-mongodb I have to make two db connections. First for the session store:

```
var connect = require('connect')
  , Db = require('mongodb').Db
  , Server = require('mongodb').Server
  , server_config = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, 
    native_parser: true})
  , db = new Db('test', server_config, {})
  , mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');

connect.createServer(
  connect.bodyParser(),
  connect.cookieParser(),
  connect.session({
    cookie: {maxAge: 60000 * 20} // 20 minutes
  , secret: 'foo'
  , store: new mongoStore({db: db})
})
);
```

Second for my mongoose connection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
....
```

this is so?

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your second question also, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb is listed on the [3rd party middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki) (session stores) page of Connect, it has the most followers (111) and it's actively updated (last update ~ 8 hours ago), so I would probably pick that one if I were you.

Edit:

About your second question, how to use connect-mongodb along with Mongoose, here's an example:

```
var connect= require('connect'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb'),
my_db = "mongodb://localhost/test",
db;

connect.createServer(
  ...
  connect.session({ store: mongoStore(my_db, secret: 'topsecret' }));
  ...
);

db = mongoose.connect(my_db);
```

Nodepad is a real app that uses Express, connect-mongodb and Mongoose, you can checkout the main app file here: https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Actually, **as of Feb 24 2013, connect-mongo beats connect-mongodb on each of these metrics**. It has ~20 more stars and 3 more forks, is also listed on the 3rd party middleware page, and is being more actively maintained (the connect-mongodb readme currently begins with a "Maintainer Needed" heading).

Also, both of them can get their connection settings from Mongoose objects.

Answer (score 2):

Connect-mongodb does the connection for you automatically. You pass in the string which is the database name and optionally a host (localhost is default). Here's how we're using it.

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: "x2kjh2323hjhjk32hjk23uhi23",
    store: new MongoStore({host: "200.11.11.11", db: 'sessions'}),
    cookie: {maxAge: 604800000}
}))
```

Comment: Updated to reflect that it's just a string. It was from a config file called hosts that was required.

Answer (score 0):

**from API doc**: unfortunately since Version 1.* I can't do that. This version is not compatible with 0.* versions. Now you must pass a mongodb connection, or server configuration. On updating, i recomment to delete your current sessions collection data